# Add header only to a location with Apache proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, content-security-policy

The problem is to set headers with apache proxy under /portal location and not other resources outside /portal.

Headers added on:
`www.example.com/portal/css/some.css`
and not:
`www.example.com/index.html`

Tested:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/portal
Header set headerKey "HeaderValue"
```

RewriteCond does not limit set header to /portal resources.

Comment: What is the Apache version?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<Location "/portal">
    Header set headerKey "HeaderValue"
</Location>
```